# How in regexp match one pattern from another?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Have a string:

```
This is a <div> simple div </div> test /n
```

How can i match: 
match_1:

```
'<div> simple div </div>'
```

and from this match_1: get second finally match?

```
'simple div'
```

Or another words: "get pattern_1 > get pattern_2(from pattern_1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use some simple capture groups in one regex query. No need to do two separate expressions:

```
.*(<div>([\w\s]+)<\/div>).*
```

Full match: `This is a <div> simple div </div> test /n`

Group 1: `<div> simple div </div>`

Group 2: `simple div`

If you're using python, you can always use `str = str.strip()` to trim any excess whitespace on group 2.